# Adding ExternalAccessory.framework

Tags: xcode, xcode4

The documentation I'm reading says:

> 1. Find the Frameworks folder name in the Groups & File section of
>      Xcode.
> 2. Select Add, Existing Frameworks by pressing the right button of the
>      mouse.
> 3. Select ExternalAccessory.framework under Frameworks and click on
>      the Add button.

In the Project Navigator, I have right-clicked the Frameworks folder, but I don't see a way of adding an existing framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XCode 4 you can add frameworks by:

- Click on the top-level project entry in the project navigator. This should cause the project settings to be shown in the main editor
- Select the target that depends on the framework you want. This should show you the settings for the specific target
- Expand the section labeled "Link Binary with Libraries" to see the frameworks and libraries being linked in
- Press the "+" button to add a framework

Comment: Thanks Tim!  "Link Binary with Libraries" is in the "Build Phases" tab.